# Convert integer array to string array

Tags: vb.net

whats the easiest way to convert an array of integers into string form? I'm trying to copy the whole array of integers into strings.

`{1, 2, 3}`

to

`{"1", "2", "3"}`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest method would be to use the `Select` extension method which is provided by LINQ:

```
Dim intArray() As Integer = {1, 2, 3}
Dim strArray() As String = intArray.Select(Function(x) x.ToString()).ToArray()
```

If you don't want to, or cannot use LINQ, you can use the `Array.ConvertAll` method, which is almost as easy:

```
 Dim strArray() As String = Array.ConvertAll(Of Integer, String)(intArray, Function(x) x.ToString())
```

**EDIT**

Based on your comments, below, it looks like you need to convert from an `ArrayList` of integers to an `ArrayList` of strings.  In that case, you could do it like this:

```
Dim intArray As New ArrayList({1, 2, 3})
Dim strArray As New ArrayList(intArray.ToArray().Select(Function(x) x.ToString()).ToArray())
```

Although, at that point, it's starting to get a bit messier.  It's probably easier to just do a standard loop, like this:

```
Dim myArray As New ArrayList({1, 2, 3})
For i As Integer = myArray.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
    myArray(i) = myArray(i).ToString()
Next
```

For what it's worth, though, unless you are still on a really old version of the .NET Framework, you really ought to be using the `List(Of T)` class rather than the `ArrayList` class, in most cases.

Comment: sorry, I should of specified that I'm using it as `ArrayList()`

Comment: So, you want to convert from an `ArrayList` containing integers to an `ArrayList` containing strings?

Comment: if that is possible, yes.

Comment: I updated my answer to show a couple ways in which you could do that.

Comment: You should use generic `List(Of T)` or `T()` instead of `ArrayList`.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek I already mentioned that in the last paragraph of my answer.